# Get previous item of ES6 loop

Tags: javascript

How do I get the previous element of an ES6 loop.

For example, if I have my for loop written like this:

```
for (let item of data){  
   console.log(item.name)
}
```

I also want to get the name of the previous item of the loop:

I tried:

```
data[item-1].name
```

which does not work.

When I used ES5 array

```
for(let i =0;i<details.length;i++){
   console.log(details[i-1].PartNumber)
}
```

gave me the previous element of the loop. I am not sure how I can do this usinf the new syntax

Comment: If you need the index, you might as well use the old syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save a reference to previous object into a separate variable.

```js
let data = [{name: 'name1'}, {name: 'name2'}, {name: 'name3'}, {name: 'name4'}, {name: 'name5'}];

let prev;
for (let item of data){  
   console.log({current: item.name, previous: prev && prev.name})
   prev = item;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to define a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) that iterates over pairs of values where each pairing has the previous and current values of that iteration. Doing this would allow you to iterate using the `for .. of` flow control in a reasonably clean and clear way.

A simple way to do that would be as follows:

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4];

/* Define generator function which returns
a pair of previous/current values from input 
iteratable, per iteration */
function *iteratePairs(iteratable) {
  
  let prev;
  
  for(const item of iteratable) {
    
    // Return the pair for this iteration
    yield [prev, item]
    
    // Update the previous item
    prev = item;
  }
  
}

// Invoke the iteratePairs generator using for..of
// flow control
for (let pair of iteratePairs(data)){  
   console.log(pair)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `for..of` *and* access the previous index, call `.entries()` on the array first, so you get both the key and the value, and then you can use bracket notation to look up the `i - 1` property:

```
for (const [i, value] of data.entries()){  
  if (i >= 1) {
    console.log(data[i - 1].PartNumber);
  }
}
```

```js
const data = [
  { PartNumber: 0 },
  { PartNumber: 1 },
  { PartNumber: 2 },
]

for (const [i, value] of data.entries()){  
  if (i >= 1) {
    console.log(data[i - 1].PartNumber);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Thats kind of the point. The ES6 for-of loop abstracts the concept of the index away, and should be used if you want a simple loop. If you want to manually access elements based on the index there is nothing wrong with using a simple `for` loop.

However what you could do is this:

```
for(let [idx, elem] of Object.entries(arr)) {
  console.log(arr[idx -1]);
}
```

But I would recommend to use a simple `for` loop.